# Rails5: How to set a variable for seed params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am seeding multiple csvs for different tables which have many similar columns. For example, the teachers and students tables have similar columns email, name, etc. So I want to shorten my seed file by putting all common things into a variable, so that:

```
puts "Seeding teachers.."
File.open("teachers.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |line, index|
    email, name, teacher_code = line.chomp.split (",")    
  Teacher.create(email: email, name: name, teacher_code: teacher_code)
  end
end

puts "Seeding students.."
File.open("students.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |line, index|
    email, name, subject = line.chomp.split (",")
  Student.create(email: email, name: name, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

becomes:

```
def common_data
    [email, mame]
end

def common_params
    ["email: email", "name: name"] # not sure
end

puts "Seeding teachers.."
File.open("teachers.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |line, index|
    common_data, teacher_code = line.chomp.split (",")    
  Teacher.create(common_params, teacher_code: teacher_code)
  end
end


puts "Seeding students.."
File.open("students.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |line, index|
    common_data, subject = line.chomp.split (",")
  Student.create(common_params, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

I get an error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `email' for main:Object
```

Comment: You might want to use `CSV` from the standard library for parsing your CSV files, it is a tricky format and sooner or later `String#split` will go wrong. Also, careful with your whitespace, `split (",")` and `split(",")` aren't quite the same thing and you don't want to acquire bad habits.

Comment: Are you required to use `CSV` files? Or do you have the liberty to use `yaml` files?

Answer (score 2):

The error is being thrown in `common_data`, yes? Because, here:

```
[email, mame]
```

(assuming "mame" is supposed to be "name") ruby expects `email` to be a variable or method. But it isn't, is it?

Perhaps you meant:

```
['email', 'name']
```

or

```
[:email, :name]
```